# Standard error of slope when data is unknown

Tags: variance, residuals, standard-error, matrix

Let’s say I did a linear regression on a dataset with 10 observations, and I got the estimated slope as $b=0.5$ and residual variance as $\sigma^2=5.2$ and further,
$$(A^TA)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix}
2.54 &  -0.21\\
 -0.21 &  0.11\\
\end{bmatrix},$$
where $A$ is the design matrix. Here we have the first column of $A$ corresponds to the intercept and the second column to the slope.

I'm just wondering how I can find the standard error of slope $b$ in this concrete example. Of course I know how to do it if I also know my data set but in this case it is unknown. Any suggestion would be helpful!

Comment: You must have learned a formula for the SE and that formula will involve $\hat\sigma^2$ and $(A^\prime A)^{-1}.$  [Look it up](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=regression+standard+error+formula+is%3Aanswer+score%3A2) and apply it.

Comment: @whuber thanks for reply! I've got this formula, $SE(\hat{\beta}_j)=\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{(A^TA)_{jj}^{-1}}$. I will try this.

Comment: So I ended with $SE(\hat{\beta}_1)=\hat{\sigma}\sqrt{(A^TA)_{11}^{-1}}=\sqrt{5.2\cdot 0.11}=0.76$.

Comment: That looks correct!  But haven't you computed the SE of the *second* coefficient, which usually would be called $\hat\beta_2$?

Comment: Ahh no, I did not compute that. Maybe I could try to do that. You were a great help. :)
Btw if I want to compute the 90% confidence interval for the slope, then I just do it as follows: $[0.5-\sqrt{5.2}\cdot 1.64,0.5+\sqrt{5.2}\cdot 1.64]=[-3.23,4.23]$? I'm new to this statistic course and I want to learn the course by give myself some exercises to practice with before my written exam in June.

Comment: You somehow lost the factor of $\sqrt{0.11}$ in your calculation.

Comment: In the confidence interval? How come?

Comment: The endpoints of the CI are determined by the standard error of the slope.

Comment: So my calculation should be $[0.5-\sqrt{5.2\cdot 0.11}\cdot 1.64,0.5+\sqrt{5.2\cdot 0.11}\cdot 1.64]=[-0.74,1.74]$